# Terraform has unexpected behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My first time running Terraform following this [tutorial](https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-tutorial)

When I reach the section on the page titled "Output Variables" and then run `terraform apply` twice I receive the below. What I don't understand is why didn't terraform create another new EC2 instance? how did it (terraform) know there is a running instance it (terraform) is assigned to and so should only return the details of that vm?

```
> terraform apply
aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm: Refreshing state... [id=i-04778c232e988be09]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

instance_id = "i-04778c232e988be09"
public_ip = "18.212.217.57"


> terraform apply
aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm: Refreshing state... [id=i-04778c232e988be09]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

instance_id = "i-04778c232e988be09"
public_ip = "18.212.217.57"
```

I have three files: `provider.tf`, `main.tf` and `variables.tf`

`provider.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.27.0"
    }
  }
}
```

`main.tf`

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_rhel9_vm" {
  ami           = var.ami //RHEL 9 AMI
  instance_type = var.type

  tags = {
    Name = var.name_tag
  }
}
```

`variables.tf`

```
variable "ami" {
  type = string
  description = "RHEL 9 AMI ID in US-East-1"
  default = "ami-05a5f6298acdb05b6"
}

variable "type" {
  type = string
  description = "Instance Type"
  default = "t2.micro"
}

variable "name_tag" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the EC2 instance"
  default = "My EC2 RHEL 9 instance"
}

output "public_ip" {
 value       = aws_instance.my_vm.public_ip
 description = "Public IP Address of EC2 instance"
}

output "instance_id" {
 value       = aws_instance.my_vm.id
 description = "Instance ID"
}

#locals {
# ami      = "ami-05a5f6298acdb05b6"
# type     = "t2.micro"
# name_tag = "My EC2 RHEL 9 instance"
#}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF maintains a [state file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state). So information about all resources that you create are stored in the statefile.

Once you run TF again, TF will check your configuration with what is stored in the  state file. If there are no changes in your TF scripts, TF will not create nor modify anything.